# What does this symbol mean (white circle connected with black bullet; both are linked by a horizontal line) and how can I write it in LaTeX?

Tags: integration, continuity, notation, fourier-transform

The symbol appears within the definition of the [Fourier transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqryy.jpg). The German text translates as follows:

> The Fourier transform of a continuous, integrable function $s(t)$ is given as
>
> *Math stuff with ominous symbol.*
>
> The equivalence $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + j\sin(x)$ is called Euler’s formula.

Comment: [Latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial

Comment: $\multimap$  This is the closest I can find so far...

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html  I don't know if this will help or not...

Comment: Well, I would need it the other way round. I think it can be made with `\circ` and `\bullet` and something inbetween, but I don’t know what.

Comment: I don't think it's a standard symbol. In this text it seems to be used to mean "is transformed to". To find out how to write it in LaTeX, try asking at http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That's not math speak, it's engineering speak. (Some) German engineers use that notation to denote the relation between a function and its Fourier or Laplace transform. I'd read it as "corresponds to" ("entspricht") if I had to.

Comment: do you mean this here $$  \multimapdotbothB $$? at page 49? and here is the link http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: This question might fit better at tex.se. But, with `unicode-math` you get this symbol via `\origof` which might be spelled out as "origin of" according to [this table](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf). It sits at slot `u+022B6`.

Comment: This kind of symbol, rather usual 40 or 30 years ago, is now very obsolete : special symbols like this one are completely superfluous. You will not find it in 99.5% of modern texts on Fourier Transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write it in LATEX you need to include the package "txfonts" and use `$\multimapdotbothA$`.

Comment: You can add a link to http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/symbol/?id=4421 to support your answer

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it means anything distinctly mathematical. I think it is read "is defined by".

Try detexify.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means "ominous symbol". :D